# odd function in $\mathbb R^n$

Tags: real-analysis

I know that even function in $\mathbb R^n$ are radial function, but what are odd function in $\mathbb R^n$ ? Are they $$u(x)=G(|x|),$$
where $G(-|x|)=-G(|x|)$ ?

Comment: $u(-x)=G(|-x|)=G(|x|)=u(x)$. Hence this characterization doesnt work for odd functionms.

Comment: Please, if you are ok, you can accept the answer and set it as solved. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You could define as $$G(x)=-G(-x)$$ with $$x\in \mathbb{R^n}$$

Answer (score 0):

If you are considering $\vert x\vert$ to be the norm of the vector $x  \in  \mathbb{R}^n$ then it means that the function $$u(x)=G(\vert x\vert) $$
is such that,  $u:\mathbb{R}^n\rightarrow\mathbb{R}^m$ to understand which we need to know more about $G$ as a function.

Now, we can clearly see that $x\in \mathbb{R}^n$ will produce the following image under the map $u$ $$x\mapsto \vert x\vert \mapsto G(\vert x\vert)$$
Now, we know that $-\vert x\vert$ has no such particular resemblance physically but, it is a *real number*.

So,if we define $G(-\vert x\vert) = -G(\vert x\vert)$ which satisfies the primary definition of odd functions, but I can't immediately see if $\exists \;\text{some}\; y \in \mathbb{R}^n \;\text{such that}\; u(y)=G(-\vert x\vert).$ So under the assumption that $\vert x\vert$ is the *Euclidean Norm* of $x\in \mathbb{R}^n$, defining such a function wont give us an odd function.